# Getting index of first object in an array that has "name" property starting with selected letter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

I have alphabetically ordered list of countries in an array like following:

```
[
  {
    name: "United States",
    country_code: "US",
    dial_code: "+1"
  },
  { .. etc }
]
```

I am listening for users key input and lets say they press "a" key. I want to get index of first object in the array where name starts with "a".

Now my question is not to how to perform this whole operation, just advice / ideas on how to find such index in the array if I already know user pressed "a". I was looking into [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to do this, but wasn't able to figure it out, hence feel free to use third party libraries if they are appropriate to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `_.findIndex` to find first matched item index:

```
var firstIndex = _.findIndex(countries, function(country) {
    return _.chain(country)
        .get('name', '')
        .lowerCase()
        .startsWith('a')
        .value();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with the first letter and an index for the access to the given array and end of the array with the same letter, like

```
var abc = {
    u: [0, 1]
}
```

Example with letter `'u'`:

```js
var countries = [{ name: "United Kingdom", country_code: "UK", dial_code: "+44" }, { name: "United States", country_code: "US", dial_code: "+1" }, { name: "France", country_code: "FR", dial_code: "+33" }, { name: "Italy", country_code: "IT", dial_code: "+16" }],
    abc = Object.create(null);

countries.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

countries.forEach(function (a, i) {
    var c = a.name[0].toLowerCase();
    if (!abc[c]) {
        abc[c] = [i];
    }
    abc[c][1] = i + 1;
});

console.log(Array.prototype.slice.apply(countries, abc['u']));
console.log(abc);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a function that would filter countries which name start with the letter given as parameter :

```js
var countries = [
  {
    name: "United States",
    country_code: "US",
    dial_code: "+1"
  },
  {   name: "France",
    country_code: "FR",
    dial_code: "+33"
  },
  {   name: "Italy",
    country_code: "IT",
    dial_code: "+16"
  }
]
var selectedCountries = (array, letter) => array.filter(x => x.name.indexOf(letter) === 0);

console.log(selectedCountries(countries, "F"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If older browsers aren't an issue, you can combine [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`String.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```
var obj = arr.find( x => x.name.startsWith('a'));
```